What numerals does Rachasap use?
I'm looking for details on the counting system in Rachasap, the royal register of Thai. It seems like they use an Indian (Pali?) system – at least I have found the numeral one, ek.

Strictly speaking, no, there are no separate numbers that specifically used in ราชาศัพท์ (raa-chaa-sàp).
However, there is a set of Pali-derived numbers for ภาษาทางกฎหมาย (paa-sǎa taang gòt-mǎai) "legal language", specifically mandated for use in เลขมาตรา (lêk mâat-dtraa) "section numbers" for alternative subsections. They correspond to where Latin bis/ter/quater/quinquie(n)s would be used (e.g. see this UN editorial manual).
Nonetheless, the usual Sino-based numbers are still well-used and standard.
The (lower!) Pali-based numbers are well known outside the legal profession though, as they function as literary numbers in e.g. Pali-/Sanskrit-derived compounds, in place names, the numbering of the tones, ranks in the army. E.g. for ตรี dtri:

ตรีปิฎก Dtrii-bpì-dòk = Tripitaka (त्रिपिटक)
ตรีทูต dtrii-tûut = at death's door, moribundity; literally त्रि "third" + दूत "agent", likely with Khmer influence ត្រីទូត
ไม้ตรี mái dtrii = ◌๊, the third tone marker
ร้อยตรี rói dtrii = sub-lieutenant


Thank you, Mr. Michaelyus,
This was exactly what I was looking for. My interest in this topic is related to my previous work:
https://philnauki.mgimo.ru/jour/article/view/476
Pavel
